Definir constante con el valor devuelto de una función
Necesito crear una constante dentro de una clase con un array devuelto de una función dentro de la misma clase
class Utils {
    const MI_CONSTANTE= self::dameDatos();
    ...
    
    public static function dameDatos(){
      $miarray = array [1, 2 ,3 ,4];
    
      return $miarray;
    }
 }

Pero me da un error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in
miclase.php linea 2


Muestra el archivo "miclase.php" completo.

El error en el código se produce porque estás intentando definir una constante de clase (MI_CONSTANTE) utilizando el valor devuelto por un método de la misma clase (self::dameDatos()), lo cual no es permitido en PHP.

Aparte de lo que te comenta @Bryro, ¿qué sentido tiene lo que intentas hacer aquí? Puedes llamar al método de este modo: Utils::dameDatos() sin necesidad de sobrecargar la clase definiendo algo que hace lo mismo que el método.

No puedes usar self:: para declarar miembros de clases.
Además, tienes un error en esta declaración: $miarray = array [1, 2 ,3 ,4];
Tú podrías quitar la declaración de la constante y llamar al método de este modo: Utils::dameDatos()
O bien declarar el array en la constante directamente.
Veamos los dos modos:
class Utils {
    public static function dameDatos(){
      return  [1, 2 ,3 ,4];
    }
 }

var_dump(Utils::dameDatos());

Salida:
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
}


class Utils {
    const MI_CONSTANTE = [1, 2 ,3 ,4];    
 }

var_dump(Utils::MI_CONSTANTE);

Salida:
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
}


Básicamente, no puedes definir una constante con algo que no es un valor literal, no puedes asignarle el retorno de una función ni de un método. Como dice @a-cedano, lo suyo es que prescindas de la constante y uses el método en su lugar, o que prescindas del método y definas el valor directamente en la constante. Yo creo que me inclinaría por lo primero.
